# Please explain the return value of GetAsyncKeyState() function in win32

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net

When we call/paste "GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F4)" into the watch window in VS2013 during a debugging session it returns 204996608. I looked at the MSDN documentation but I can't figure out how to understand that number. What is it trying to tell me?

Comment: That's not a possible return value.  You are doing something wrong.

Comment: I  took the function GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F4) and pasted it into the "WATCH" window in VS2010. That is the value it gave me.

Comment: why the negative votes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx:

> If the function succeeds, the return value specifies whether the key
>   was pressed since the last call to GetAsyncKeyState, and whether the
>   key is currently up or down. If the most significant bit is set, the
>   key is down, and if the least significant bit is set, the key was
>   pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState. However, you
>   should not rely on this last behavior; for more information, see the
>   Remarks.

Which means you need to check the most significant bit to see if the key was pressed:

```
bool f4Pressed = (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F4) & (1 << 15)) != 0;
```

Comment: GAKS returns a short: 'Holds signed 16-bit (2-byte) integers that range in value from -32,768 through 32,767'

Comment: I took the function GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F4) and pasted it into the "WATCH" window in VS2010. That is the value it gave me

Comment: Have you used SHORT as the variable type that contains GetASyncKeyState()'s return value?

Comment: Just pasted: "GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F4)" into the VS watch window and got that number as the value. Try it, what do you get?

Comment: I just tested the function(which the key 'H'). When I hold it pressed, the function returns -32767 which is correct. Here's the code:
`#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
 Sleep(1000);
 SHORT res = GetAsyncKeyState(0x48);

    return 0;
}`

Comment: If you put a watch on "res", you should see the correct result

Comment: Yeah, that seems to work... weird that you need to store it in a variable for the watch window to show it correctly...

Answer (score 2):

GAKS returns a short int, ie. 16-bit integer, with the MSB set or not.

So, just get your return type correct and then test if it's negative.

Comment: I took the function GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F4) and pasted it into the "WATCH" window in VS2010. That is the value it gave me